# List of files accessed while compiling

Tags: c, compilation

I'm compiling a huge project in C, but I think there are many files which are not being used. Is there any way, I can get a list of files which are being used/accessed during compilation.

Comment: Nothing to do with C, but in a Posix environment you should find a find which has an "-anewer <file>" test. If the comparison file is a source file which you modified immediately before building, you should get all files which were accessed after that, i.e. were used in the build. All others can be deleted (if not needed in other circumstances, as remarked below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the compiler. With GCC, you can use `-H` to get a list of all the files included.  For example, I have a file `itobase.c` which compiles to a program when `-DTEST` is specified.

The source contains:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "stderr.h"

…code…

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

…test code…
```

With the `-H` option, `gcc` generated:

```
$ gcc -I. -H -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DJLSS_STDERR -O2 -fPIC -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall \
>     -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror \
>     -DTEST -o itobase itobase.c /Users/jleffler/lib/64/libjl.a  
. /usr/include/assert.h
.. /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
... /usr/include/sys/_symbol_aliasing.h
... /usr/include/sys/_posix_availability.h
. /usr/include/string.h
.. /usr/include/_types.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types.h
.... /usr/include/machine/_types.h
..... /usr/include/i386/_types.h
.. /usr/include/Availability.h
... /usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_null.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_ssize_t.h
.. /usr/include/strings.h
... /usr/include/string.h
.. /usr/include/secure/_string.h
... /usr/include/secure/_common.h
. /usr/include/unistd.h
.. /usr/include/sys/unistd.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_posix_vdisable.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_seek_set.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_gid_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_off_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_pid_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_uid_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_useconds_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/select.h
... /usr/include/sys/appleapiopts.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_fd_def.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_timespec.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_timeval.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_time_t.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_suseconds_t.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_sigset_t.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_fd_setsize.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_fd_set.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_fd_clr.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_fd_isset.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_fd_zero.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_fd_copy.h
... /usr/include/sys/_select.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_dev_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_mode_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_uuid_t.h
.. /usr/include/gethostuuid.h
. /usr/include/inttypes.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_wchar_t.h
.. /usr/gcc/v4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.2/include/stdint.h
... /usr/gcc/v4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.2/include-fixed/stdint.h
. stderr.h
.. config.h
.. /usr/include/stdio.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h
... /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h
.. /usr/gcc/v4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.2/include/stdarg.h
. /usr/include/stdlib.h
.. /usr/include/sys/wait.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types/_id_t.h
... /usr/include/sys/signal.h
.... /usr/include/machine/signal.h
..... /usr/include/i386/signal.h
.... /usr/include/machine/_mcontext.h
..... /usr/include/i386/_mcontext.h
...... /usr/include/mach/i386/_structs.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_types/_sigaltstack.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_types/_ucontext.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_types/_pthread_attr_t.h
... /usr/include/sys/resource.h
... /usr/include/machine/endian.h
.... /usr/include/i386/endian.h
..... /usr/include/sys/_endian.h
...... /usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h
....... /usr/include/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h
.. /usr/include/alloca.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_ct_rune_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_rune_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_wchar_t.h
.. /usr/include/machine/types.h
... /usr/include/i386/types.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_types/_int8_t.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_types/_int16_t.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_types/_int32_t.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_types/_int64_t.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_types/_uintptr_t.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_types/___offsetof.h
Multiple include guards may be useful for:
/usr/include/assert.h
/usr/include/machine/_mcontext.h
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h
/usr/include/secure/_string.h
/usr/include/sys/_posix_availability.h
/usr/include/sys/_symbol_aliasing.h
config.h
$
```

The names preceded by a single dot are those directly included in the source.  The rest are indirectly included from the files that are directly included.

Compilation with GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Comment: On MS you can do the same with /showIncludes flag when using cl.exe or Project Properties/Advanced/ShowIncludes in the IDE.

Comment: This works perfectly fine, and is there anyway to find the files accessed during runtime? Like an image, text file etc etc.

Comment: Usually yes, but the details vary dramatically from system to system.  On Unix-like systems, there is typically a program such as `truss` or `strace` or `dtrace` or … which can record every system call made, and from the log of that you can determine which files are accessed.  There are equivalent facilities on Windows, though the details are very different.

Answer (score 1):

C does not offer what you want.

- You can search for every header files, whether they are included somewhere. But if a group of files are unused but include each other, you'd miss them.
- You have to remove file by file and try to compile / run it. If it fails, the file is needed. But be aware that some files could be used conditionally, either depending on compilation options, your target platform and on external libraries.
- Maybe your IDE or build system does offer this, depending on what you use. An example: If you have unit tests you could use the code coverage from GCC to see which source files are not covered. You could investigate these files further.

So in general, I don't see a feasible way. And you have to be really careful to not remove files that are unused in your configuration but might be required for other people / use cases.